# Making changes to an immutable string in Python

Tags: python, string

I'd like some help with the following code:

```
def mutate_string(string, position, character):
    res=list(string)
    res[position] = 'character'
    s=''.join(res)
    print(s)

a = str(input())
b,c = input().split()

mutate_string(a,b,c)
```

When I try to give `b` and `c` as separate inputs without using split function the output seems to be fine but multiple inputs in a single line throws me the below error:

```
abcdefg
5 h
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Bhargav/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_27.py", 
line 11, in <module>
mutate_string(a,b,c)
File "C:/Users/Bhargav/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_27.py", 
line 3, in mutate_string
res[position] = 'character'
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: You've tried to index into a list with a string as the index `"5"`. Convert it to an integer. Also, you're putting not the variable `character`, but the literal string `"character"` into that position (once you fix the first problem).

Comment: b needs to be an integer, but is a string after you read it. Convert it: `b = int(b)`

Comment: Also note that your function is not using the `character` argument, but instead uses a hardcoded string `'character'`.

Comment: In addition, your function name is misleading. You are not mutating a string. You are building a new string and printing it.

Comment: change 
    res[position] = 'character'
into 
    res[position] = character